# How to skip first line of a file and read the remaining lines as input of a C program?

Tags: linux, shell

How to write the shell command to skip the first line in file `a.csv` and redirect the remaining lines as input to `myProgram`, which is my C program?

I wrote

```
./myProgram < a.csv | tail -n + 2
```

But this does not work, it seems like it will skip the first line of the output from `myProgram`.

Comment: Then how can I merge that a.csv with a new file called b.csv

Comment: Don't ask additional questions in comments.

Answer (score 14):

Erm...

```
tail -n +2 a.csv | ./myProgram
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to skip the first line, the traditional solution is `sed`:

```
sed -e 1d a.csv | ./myProgram
```

Answer (score 1):

If your shell is Bash, it supports [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution): a mechanism that lets you treat the output of a command just like a file. So instead of what you wrote, you can use

```
./myProgram < <(tail -n +2 a.csv)
```

What *your* command did instead was to use the *complete* file `a.csv` as the input to `myProgram`, then pipe the output to `tail -n + 2` (did you really use a space between `+` and `2`?).